# Cannot select some rows with npgsql on a "Portuguese" database

Tags: c#, postgresql, encoding, dapper, npgsql

I have a postgresql database that was created with "SQL_ASCII" and template "template0". It holds data in Portuguese so I have data such as "Não", "Feijão", "Avô". When I try to retrieve rows that have these kind of characters "~^" it does not work, otherwise it works.

Errors:

- "Error parsing column 6 (sempresa=0   - String)"}
- Message = "Can not convert byte [C3] in index 0 of the code page specified for Unicode."

I'm using Npgsql and Dapper

```
<packages>
  <package id="Dapper" version="1.50.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Npgsql" version="3.1.7" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I searched a lot but nothing works. I've tried:

Setting up client encoding in connection string:

```
var sqlBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    Host = host,
                    Database = database,
                    Username = user,
                    Password = password,
                    Pooling = false,
                    ClientEncoding = "SQL_ASCII" 
                    // I also tried "UNICODE", "utf8", "win-1252"
                };
```

I also tried to run a non-query command to change enconding before selecting

```
 // I tried a lot of encondings: SQL_ASCII, win-1252, unicode
 connection.Execute("set client_encoding = 'SQL_ASCII'");

 var data = connection.Query<T>(strSQL);
```

I CANNOT change database encoding or recreate database sinse the application will run against lots of production databases.

I hope nobody flags this question as duplicated sinse I really tried to solve with other questions but nothing I found worked.

Comment: Hmm... Npgsql currently reads UTF8 and relies on the server to do conversions from the server encoding. In other words, if a database uses encoding WIN1252, PostgreSQL will transparently convert that to UTF8. However, SQL-ASCII is a special "non-encoding" which disables all conversions. In other words, it seems like you have data in WIN1252, but PostgreSQL doesn't know about it (because you're in SQL-ASCII) - that is a bad setup.

Comment: Am not sure what exactly can be done for you. It's possible to add support for non-UTF8 encodings to Npgsql, in which case Npgsql will decode the incoming (unconverted) data in whichever way you specify. This would be issue https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/392, which was closed because of lack of interest. I've reopened that issue, it shouldn't be too hard to do. Please go vote there.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But we gave up on npgsql. We are using Odbc, and rebuild the wheel writing our own ORM.

Comment: Oh dear, I'm just in the process of implementing support for your case (i.e. arbitrary .NET encodings)...

Comment: Oh thought it would take discussion, approval etc. If it gets fixed I can use npg again. I have an abstraction layer that will make changes easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added support for non-UTF8 encodings to Npgsql. This should really be used only in special edge cases such as this, where the database was created with SQL_ASCII, contains non-ASCII characters, and an encoding change is impossible.

I've backported this support to the next patch version, 3.1.8 (seems harmless enough). There's some trouble with the build server at the moment, but if you wait a few days you should have a CI package of 3.1.8 available with the new support at http://myget.org/gallery/npgsql. Follow https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/392 for more updates/progress.

Comment: FYI a CI package for 3.1.8 with this feature is available at https://www.myget.org/feed/npgsql, using that should be OK. You should also accept this answer.

Comment: I download the 3.1.8 package on myget.org and in my connection string added:  Encoding = "windows-1252", ClientEncoding = "sql-ascii"  and now it's working! Thanks so much that @Shay

Comment: Great, happy to hear it worked - 3.1.8 will probably be released soon. Note that it's still a really good idea to avoid SQL_ASCII where at all possible!