# Encoding problem using npgsql entityFrameworkCore with old ascii postgresql database

Tags: c#, postgresql, encoding, npgsql

I have an old postgresql database (in production) that uses ascii encoding.
I'm creating a new c# .net application using npgsql entityFrameWorkCore but I always get encoding errors:

System.Text.DecoderFallbackException : Unable to translate bytes [xx] at index yy from specified code page to Unicode

I found this similar problem:

[Cannot select some rows with npgsql on a "Portuguese" database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145146/cannot-select-some-rows-with-npgsql-on-a-portuguese-database)

It looks on that page that support was added for non-ascii characters.
But this does not seem to work in npgsql 2.2
Upgrading the database is no option.
Any idea what I can do to read my data?

Answer (score 0):

As written in the issue you've linked to above, the support for non-UTF8 encoding was added to Npgsql 3.1.8 - so 2.2 doesn't have it. 2.2 is also really old by now (and completely unmaintained/unsupported) - you should upgrade to the latest version of Npgsql (note this doesn't imply upgrading your database).

Comment: I have checked my version for package and I still get the same problem, I can't read data from table

Comment: Can you please open another question or issue with the full details?